# Label is not working properly

Tags: bibliographies, labels

I was trying to give labeling in my definition and also while writing the bibliography the following output is coming. I don't know why. Please help me.

Thanks!!!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epic,eepic}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibl.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
%\usepackage[small,nohug,heads=vee]{diagrams}
%\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}




\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[thm]
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem*{coro}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{result}{Result}



\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{note}[thm]{Note}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


%Mathbf font

\newcommand{\Abf}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\Bbf}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\Cbf}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\Dbf}{\mathbf{D}}
\newcommand{\Ebf}{\mathbf{E}}
\newcommand{\Fbf}{\mathbf{F}}
\newcommand{\Gbf}{\mathbf{G}}
\newcommand{\Hbf}{\mathbf{H}}
\newcommand{\Ibf}{\mathbf{I}}
\newcommand{\Jbf}{\mathbf{J}}
\newcommand{\Kbf}{\mathbf{K}}
\newcommand{\Lbf}{\mathbf{L}}
\newcommand{\Mbf}{\mathbf{M}}
\newcommand{\Nbf}{\mathbf{N}}
\newcommand{\Obf}{\mathbf{O}}
\newcommand{\Pbf}{\mathbf{P}}
\newcommand{\Qbf}{\mathbf{Q}}
\newcommand{\Rbf}{\mathbf{R}}
\newcommand{\Sbf}{\mathbf{S}}
\newcommand{\Tbf}{\mathbf{T}}
\newcommand{\Ubf}{\mathbf{U}}
\newcommand{\Vbf}{\mathbf{V}}
\newcommand{\Wbf}{\mathbf{W}}
\newcommand{\Xbf}{\mathbf{X}}
\newcommand{\Ybf}{\mathbf{Y}}
\newcommand{\Zbf}{\mathbf{Z}}


%Mathbb font
\newcommand{\Abb}{\mathbb{A}}
\renewcommand{\Bbb}{\mathbb{B}}
\newcommand{\Cbb}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Dbb}{\mathbb{D}}
\newcommand{\Ebb}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\Fbb}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\Gbb}{\mathbb{G}}
\newcommand{\Hbb}{\mathbb{H}}
\newcommand{\Ibb}{\mathbb{I}}
\newcommand{\Jbb}{\mathbb{J}}
\newcommand{\Kbb}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\Lbb}{\mathbb{L}}
\newcommand{\Mbb}{\mathbb{M}}
\newcommand{\Nbb}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Obb}{\mathbb{O}}
\newcommand{\Pbb}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\Qbb}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Rbb}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Sbb}{\mathbb{S}}
\newcommand{\Tbb}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\Ubb}{\mathbb{U}}
\newcommand{\Vbb}{\mathbb{V}}
\newcommand{\Wbb}{\mathbb{W}}
\newcommand{\Xbb}{\mathbb{X}}
\newcommand{\Ybb}{\mathbb{Y}}
\newcommand{\Zbb}{\mathbb{Z}}

%Mathsf font

\newcommand{\Amsf}{\mathsf{A}}
\newcommand{\Bmsf}{\mathsf{B}}
\newcommand{\Cmsf}{\mathsf{C}}
\newcommand{\Dmsf}{\mathsf{D}}
\newcommand{\Emsf}{\mathsf{E}}
\newcommand{\Fmsf}{\mathsf{F}}
\newcommand{\Gmsf}{\mathsf{G}}
\newcommand{\Hmsf}{\mathsf{H}}
\newcommand{\Imsf}{\mathsf{I}}
\newcommand{\Jmsf}{\mathsf{J}}
\newcommand{\Kmsf}{\mathsf{K}}
\newcommand{\Lmsf}{\mathsf{L}}
\newcommand{\Mmsf}{\mathsf{M}}
\newcommand{\Nmsf}{\mathsf{N}}
\newcommand{\Omsf}{\mathsf{O}}
\newcommand{\Pmsf}{\mathsf{P}}
\newcommand{\Qmsf}{\mathsf{Q}}
\newcommand{\Rmsf}{\mathsf{R}}
\newcommand{\Smsf}{\mathsf{S}}
\newcommand{\Tmsf}{\mathsf{T}}
\newcommand{\Umsf}{\mathsf{U}}
\newcommand{\Vmsf}{\mathsf{V}}
\newcommand{\Wmsf}{\mathsf{W}}
\newcommand{\Xmsf}{\mathsf{X}}
\newcommand{\Ymsf}{\mathsf{Y}}
\newcommand{\Zmsf}{\mathsf{Z}}


%Mathcal font
\newcommand{\Amcal}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\Bmcal}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\Cmcal}{\mathcal{C}}
\newcommand{\Dmcal}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\Emcal}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\Fmcal}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\Gmcal}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\Hmcal}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\Imcal}{\mathcal{I}}
\newcommand{\Jmcal}{\mathcal{J}}
\newcommand{\Kmcal}{\mathcal{K}}
\newcommand{\Lmcal}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\Mmcal}{\mathcal{M}}
\newcommand{\Nmcal}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\Omcal}{\mathcal{O}}
\newcommand{\Pmcal}{\mathcal{P}}
\newcommand{\Qmcal}{\mathcal{Q}}
\newcommand{\Rmcal}{\mathcal{R}}
\newcommand{\Smcal}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\Tmcal}{\mathcal{T}}
\newcommand{\Umcal}{\mathcal{U}}
\newcommand{\Vmcal}{\mathcal{V}}
\newcommand{\Wmcal}{\mathcal{W}}
\newcommand{\Xmcal}{\mathcal{X}}
\newcommand{\Ymcal}{\mathcal{Y}}
\newcommand{\Zmcal}{\mathcal{Z}}


\newcommand{\Rmcalp}{\mathcal{R}^\prime}

\newcommand{\pal}{\phi_\alpha}



\newcommand{\Cx}{\mathcal{C}\big(X,\mathbb{C}\big)}
\newcommand{\Cab}{\mathcal{C}\big([a,b],\mathbb{R}\big)}
\newcommand{\Mal}{M_\alpha}


\begin{document}
    "\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$ \blacksquare $}

\begin{thm}\label{key}
    Let $ \Rmcal=\Cx .$ Then
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
    Let $ \Imcal $ be any ideal of $ \Rmcal. $
\end{proof}
 \begin{definition}\label{Definition 1}
    Something........ \ref{Definition 1}
 \end{definition}

 \begin{thebibliography}{}
    \bibitem{book} T.Amaranath, {\em Elementary Course in Partial Differential Equation}, Second edition, Narosa Publication.
    \bibitem{book} L.C.Evans, {\em Partial Differential Equations,} American Mathematical Society, 2010
    \bibitem{book} S. Kesavan , {\em Topics in Functional Analysis and Applications ,} Wiley-Blackwell
 \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome (2) please provide a full minimal example that we can copy and try. Here document class and preamble is missing. Also your question is not really clear.

Comment: okay, I'll some more texts.

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{showkeys}`

Comment: If the framed boxes are meant: Remove `showkeys`

Comment: Incidentally, it is not a good idea to have three bibliography items all called "book".

Comment: This is why it is a bad idea to use numbers in labels like `\label{Definition 1}` it confuses you when the actual typeset number is different, it is much better to use some name such as `\label{Definition-of-something}`

Comment: Also be very careful with the use of renewcommand, only use it on macros you know exactly what does. Just casual redefining macros here and there makes it harder to merge your contribution with others, for example in a conference proceedings. Using the char type as a prefix rather than a postfix might be easier to read (in code form). Btw thumbs up for actually making macros for those instead of writing the completely out each time

Comment: Okay @daleif I will keep these things in my mind.